# windows 10 - Intel ethernet I219-V(2) - some kind of DHCP issue?

Tags: networking, ethernet, dhcp

I am trying to get my windows 10 machine with an intel ethernet I912-V (2) connected to an ethernet network. The ethernet constantly gives me a "limited" connection.

`ipconfig /all` shows that the ethernet adapter has a `169.xxx` address, which after some research indicated a DHCP issue?

the cable and network are fine (I am using both of them on my laptop to post this). The network is not under my control, so I cannot reset/restart them. `ipconfig /release` and `/renew` fail when I run them.

drivers are up-to-date, fresh from intel.

here is the output of `ipconfig /all`

```
Ethernet adapter ethernet:

    Connection-specific DNS suffix  . :
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1C-1B-0D-16-70-0B
    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
    Link-Local IPv6 Address . . . . . : [I honestly don't want to type this]
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Is this on a home network or a school/work network?  Does the DHCP Server/router use MAC address filtering?

Comment: Please [edit] and include the full output from `ipconfig /all`.

Comment: I think you meant a 169.x.x.x address in which case, yes, you didn't get issued one through DHCP. If you meant 192.x.x.x then you likely did. You can verify the IP was from DHCP by the Lease obtained field.

Comment: heavyd: a school network, I do not know if the DHCP server/router uses MAC filtering

Comment: 169.254.x.y addresses are zero-conf/AVAHI addresses, which are not generally functional except in a network that is set up to deal with them (and most are not). It is a standard windows fallback if the DHCP server could not be reached within the timeout interval. On rare occasions I've noticed a statically assigned interface will take on a zero-conf address after reboot, and in that case it usually works to disable and then re-enable the nic from within windows.

Comment: @frank: yes, my prior research lead me to this conclusion, that somehow my computer was not receiving an IP from the network. I am wondering if this is fixable, or I just need to deep-6 my motherboard, and send it back (it's within warranty)

Comment: I'd start by disabling IPv6 unless you know the network uses it.